# SimpleJdbcCall doesn't work for a stored function

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, db2, stored-functions

I am trying to execute a stored function on DB2 from Java. The function and code that calls it are very similar to those from Spring documentation's example https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-simple-jdbc-call-3. Here's the function declaration:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ST_CLIENT_SEGMENT( p_oib VARCHAR(11) )
    RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
    NO EXTERNAL ACTION
```

Here's the code:

```
//version1
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
    .withSchemaName("VLIB").
    .withFunctionName("ST_CLIENT_SEGMENT")
SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("p_oib", "123");
return simpleJdbcCall.executeFunction(String.class, in);

//version2
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
    .withSchemaName("VLIB")
    .withFunctionName("ST_CLIENT_SEGMENT");
simpleJdbcCall.declareParameters(new SqlParameter("p_oib", Types.VARCHAR));
return simpleJdbcCall.executeFunction(String.class, "123");

//the same exception
//Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0440] Routine ST_CLIENT_SEGMENT in VLIB not found with specified parameters.
```

Does anyone know why this happens? When I call the function from my SQL client everything works fine.

Comment: A lot of databases don't allow functions to be called in isolation (because then they would just be stored procedures), you could try to use a function, eg in a select query.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel As I said, it works from my SQL client (the same user). "values vlib.st_client_segment('123');" or "select VLIB.ST_CLIENT_SEGMENT('123') from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;"

Comment: You are assuming that is equivalent to what is constructed by SimpleJdbcCall. It could very well not be (looking at the code, it is actually constructing a JDBC escape: `{? = call vlib.st_client_segment(?)}`, which then needs to be translated by the JDBC driver. It might very well be that the DB2 JDBC driver only supports executing stored procedures with the JDBC call escape, so it might generate SQL that is invalid for calling a function.

Answer (score 2):

A colleague of mine have found a solution. It seems this is a DB2 problem http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg102506-story01.html.
I try another SQL that also gave me an exception

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("values vlib.ST_CLIENT_SEGMENT(?)", new Object[] {oib}, String.class);
//Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0418] Use of parameter marker not valid.
```

After this change everything works fine

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("values vlib.ST_CLIENT_SEGMENT( CAST( ? as CHAR) )", new Object[] {oib}, String.class);
```